# Javax.mail - Cannot get different values from bodypart type

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have a problem while getting different lines on the Content-Disposition of an email.

The source code of the email message appears to me like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

-----=_Part_0_1360890360.1452693261504
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

File Attached
------=_Part_0_1360890360.1452693261504
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
    name*0="privat_20140711133201_7702_01_20140117-FPLux-AERT-reporting";
    name*1="-amended-between-31.12.2011-to-31.12.2013.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename*0="privat_20140711133201_7702_01_20140117-FPLux-AERT-reporting";
    filename*1="-amended-between-31.12.2011-to-31.12.2013.xls"
```

The file is somehow being separated from each other. When running a debug on my code the second name or filename does not appear, only the first value. In this case only `application/octet-stream;name=privat_20140711133201_7702_01_20140117-FPLux-AERT-reporting`.
The other part simply disappear.

Can someone please help me know how to get the filename*1 to concat both strings?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of JavaMail.  Upgrade to the [latest version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), which handles this for you.  Or, for JavaMail 1.4.1 or newer, set the System property `mail.mime.decodeparameters` to "true".

Comment: The problem is that I can not get the same source in my code. The thing I get on my console when `mail.debug` is `3 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" ("charset" "us-ascii") NIL NIL "7bit" 13 0 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("application" "octet-stream" ("name" "privat_20140711133201_7702_01_20140117-FPLux-AERT-reporting") NIL NIL ...`. So I'm not able to get the source as was expected. I already tried all the mail flags I found fot decode, fold, fetch ... and nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples)?  What version of JavaMail are you using?  Can you update your post with your code and with the debug output?

Comment: I made a mistake with the properties. I didn't used the `System.properties` I did instead used only the `Class Properties` for authentication. So, your advice solved my issue. Not with the `decodeparameters` but with `System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");` or `System.setProperty("mail.mime.splitlongparameters", "false");`. The parameters method from javamail have a condition that when one of this properties is true than it split the parameters. Thank you Bill

Comment: It actually looks like the bug is in your IMAP server.  It's not properly combining the two parts and returning it as a single value, nor is it returning the two parts as separate values.  Configuring JavaMail so that it doesn't split the long names may be the only solution.

Comment: Actually yes,  the problem is within the email server. But for now this solution fixed the immediate problem. But now that you mention it, do you know how I can change the flags on exchange? Or some other way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: If you're using Exchange, you should report the problem to Microsoft.  Are you using the latest version with all the latest patches?

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the server so I'm not able to check any possibilities to fix the problem. In that way for now I'm gonna stay with what I have. Thank once again Bill